# Best way to force a function to wait another

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In my code, I use a function in another, where the inner one returns a value. Like that:

```
function first(){
    /*do stuff*/
    return stuff;
}
function second(){
    var result = first;
}
```

But my problem is the second function doesn't wait the first one and thus, I get a undefined return.

How can I force a function to wait another to get a synchronous function ?

Comment: If your /*do stuff*/ is asynchronous (like a web call, etc.), then 'return stuff;' does not do what you think it does.  It will only return the value of 'stuff' from before the async call.  So, as Terry said, a Promise might be the way to go.  You could also set up a listener for 'do stuff' to call on completion.  This would then have the result of 'do stuff', which you can then process.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a promise for this, return a promise from the first..

As in:

```
function first(){
  /*do stuff*/
  return Promise.resolve(stuff);
}

first().then((stuff) => {
    second(stuff);
});
```

A slightly more concrete example, let's do some asynch. stuff:

```
function first(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'stuff');
    });
}

function second(stuff){
    console.log('second: ', stuff);
}

first().then((stuff) => {
    second(stuff);
});
```

In newer versions of Node.js you can also do:

```
var testIt = async function()
{
    var result = await first();
    second(result);
}

testIt();
```

This is a little syntactical sugar that makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: How does it work ?

Comment: So a promise allows you to defer a result from a function, it's really another way of dealing with asynchronous code, in a more readable way.

Comment: @TerryLennox I know this is not the way to ask for help..,but I am in desperate need for it.,,Can you please have a look at this..,I have almost solved it https://stackoverflow.com/q/48966201/6345816

Comment: I will, though I am confused too!