# How to solve Arango query promise error?

Tags: node.js, promise, arangodb, aql

I have been trying to get a query result from Arangodb in to my front end service (Angular 4) using soap message. I am able to get a result of the query but printed out in console.log. But how can I get it under this function (Service).

So that I can feed into the soap message:

```js
var soap_msg = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:examples:CheckUserNameService">' +
  '<soapenv:Header/>' +
  '<soapenv:Body>' +
  '<urn:CheckUserNameResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
  '<status xsi:type="xsd:string">' + (Service) + '</status>' +
  '</urn:CheckUserNameResponse>' +
  '</soapenv:Body>' +
  '</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

I posted this issue got a response saying to use **await or .this()**, then I have updated my code but still the error remains.

I have tried to feed in to a random variable with some string like this to check the soap msg.,

```
var payload = [null,"192.168.72.237"];
```

it works fine.There is a problem with query

```js
var Service = db.query(aqlQuery `
             LET startVertex = (FOR doc IN spec
             FILTER doc.serial_no == '"123456abcde"'
             LIMIT 2
             RETURN doc
             )[0]

            FOR v IN 1 ANY startVertex belongs_to
            RETURN v.ip`, {
  bindVar1: 'value',
  bindVar2: 'value',
}).then(function(res) {
  console.log("doc" + res._result);
})
```

The versions are

- "node": "8.9.4"
- "arangojs": "^5.8.0",
- "express": "^4.16.2",
- "express-generator": "^4.15.5"

I don't have a clue to take it forward from here.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, the `doc.serial_no` you are looking for there has double quotes inside single quotes, so that means the key `serial_no` would need to have the value `"123456abcde"` with the double quotes in it. Remember to remove the double quotes if they aren't in there.

Comment: You haven't even posted the relevant code. The problem is still that `Service` is a promise, and how you're using the `Service` value elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidThomas no but the query works fine normally.It is troublesome when the service is fed into the soap msg

Comment: @Bergi I am using the service value in the soap_msg mentioned above.I am sending the soap_msg to angular4

Comment: Yes, and you cannot just put the promise object in that string. You need to wait for the promise, and then concatenate its result with the string to create the soap message.

Comment: @Bergi I didnt know how to do that ? can you guide me through it ?

Comment: @yuvii_10 I added a sample below, see how it goes for you.

Comment: As I think I have noted to you before, a question featuring begging is probably written in a rush, and questions written in a rush are rarely good questions. Please note that readers do not care how long you have been stuck, and being stuck for a long time does not (and should not) cause your question to be prioritised. **Volunteers will answer questions that they like, and they will do so at their leisure**.

Comment: Additionally, if you could refrain from adding pleading statements like "please help me out" to all of your material, it would be appreciated. Readers do not want you to scrape and beg in front of the community - keep your questions succinct, detailed, well-researched and unique, and you will do much better.

Comment: @halfer yes, I have took your advice and I was framing my questions in proper manner..,I will avoid those comments in future .Thank you for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the promise resolve for you, it's necessary to invoke the `.all` function of the cursor so that it will return the values.

[This site](https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/a-quick-tour-of-arangojs/) has a good example which is simply:

```
db.query('FOR doc IN documents RETURN doc')
  .then((cursor) => { return cursor.all() })
  .then((doc) => { console.log(doc) });
```

The promise returned by the first step is then invoked to extract the records, and the return from the cursor is the documents you're looking for.

e.g.

```
var Service = db.query(aqlQuery `
             LET startVertex = (FOR doc IN spec
             FILTER doc.serial_no == '"123456abcde"'
             LIMIT 2
             RETURN doc
             )[0]

            FOR v IN 1 ANY startVertex belongs_to
            RETURN v.ip`, {
  bindVar1: 'value',
  bindVar2: 'value',
}).then(function(cursor) { // Add this to return the documents in the promise
     return cursor.all()  
}).then(function(res) {
  console.log("doc" + res._result);
})
```